# How do I export banshee library settings to another machine?

Tags: banshee, downgrade, libraries, database, metadata

I am trying to downgrade my distro. The thing is, I have spent some few hours organising my music library and I do not want to lose my database. I have checked 'write meta data to files'. And so, my understanding is, that if I just import those same mp3s into a new library, those files will be arranged in the same order in the library. But this doesn't sound like a safe enough option. I'm moving from 11.10 to 10.04. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- newbie

Answer (score 6):

The Banshee configurations are stored in the `~/.config/banshee-1/` directory. Those configurations can be found in the `~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db` (if you have the `sqlite3` tool you can take a look inside this file).

I don't know if there are significant differences in the format of the files from one version to another, but I suggest that you save the entire directory and try to restore it after downgrade.

**Update:**

A more safe option to keep bashee settings is using the `sqlite3` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sqlite3
$ cd ~/.config/banshee-1
$ sqlite3 banshee.db ".dump" > BACKUP_FILE
```

After the downgrade you can restore the file (first copy the backup file to the `~/.config/banshee-1` directory):

```
$ cd ~/.config/banshee-1
$ cat BACKUP_FILE | sqlite3 banshee.db
```

Comment: thanks for that Rafael. I will use downgrading as a last resort. For now i might just try to see if i can find out how to stop banshee from crashing or how to export the library to another app like rhythmbox. Thanks so much. Gauranga!

Comment: nityabaddha, I think that some Ubuntu users will need this tool, since Rhythmbox is returning to be the default player in Ubuntu 12...