# Moving Banshee music to another computer

Tags: banshee, music, transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I export banshee library settings to another machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79656/how-do-i-export-banshee-library-settings-to-another-machine)

On my laptop I have many gigabytes of music that I ordered with album art on Banshee.

I have just bought a desktop computer and I would like to move my Banshee library across. I cannot simply move the music files as the files themselves are not all properly tagged.

Is there any way to simply transfer my hours of diligent sorting to my new computer?

Comment: These kinds of questions always puzzle me. You can tell Banshee to write metadata to files. Did you turn this off? If so, what for?

Comment: EpsilonVector thanks, sometimes you need to ask a stupid question to see the answer staring you in the face

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the settings then you should also copy over the `~/.config/banshee-1` folder. This folder is where Banshee keeps all of its configuration information and if you move it to your new computer all of your settings should be preserved.